# LINQ Query - how order by?

Tags: linq, entity-framework, silverlight-4.0, sql-order-by

In debug i get

> m_tableContext.TemplateTables.OrderBy(a => a.id)  Expression cannot contain lambda expressions

```
private readonly TamplateTableContext m_tableContext = new TamplateTableContext();

m_tableContext.Load(m_tableContext.GetTemplateTableQuery());    

lbTemplateTable.DataContext = m_tableContext.TemplateTables.OrderBy(a => a.id);
```

How do sort ?

Comment: What parameter is OrderBy() expecting?

Comment: I need sort from ID (4,3,2,1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if that is one method call, it wont work. Silverlight calls are asynchronous you have to provide a callback for the Load method so that when its done it dumps to a new method....

```
private readonly TamplateTableContext m_tableContext = new TamplateTableContext();

m_tableContext.Load(m_tableContext.GetTemplateTableQuery(),onLoadOperationCompleted);    


public void onLoadOperationCompleted(LoadOperation<TemplateTable> lo)
        {
            if (!lo.HasError)
            {
               lbTemplateTable.DataContext = 
                  new ObservableCollection<TemplateTable>(lo.Entities.OrderBy(a => a.id));
            }
}
```

Its a contrived example. I use MVVMLight and a ServiceLocator pattern, so what I am showing you isnt really in context because it looks like you may actually be doing it all in code behind...but I was really just trying to show you how to do the callback.

Comment: RoomsContext.Load(RoomsContext.GetTableQuery(), LoadBehavior.MergeIntoCurrent, onLoadOperationCompleted, new object());  - is error...

Answer (score 2):

it's a bit hard to tell by the current code. Example below uses the same OrderBy expression, and it compiles and runs ok.

```
public class A { public int ID; }

public static void Test()
{
    List<A> listA = new List<A> {new A {ID=7}, new A {ID=2}, new A {ID=16}};

    var query1 = from x in listA orderby x.ID select x;
    var query2 = (from x in listA select x).OrderBy(a => a.ID);

    foreach(var x1 in query1) Console.WriteLine("{0}", x1.ID);
    foreach(var x2 in query2) Console.WriteLine("{0}", x2.ID);
}
```

Error you have might actually come from insufficient information about key data type. [This](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/linqprojectgeneral/thread/ddd18a4a-c67a-4d0c-a07d-3e2180454a52/) discussion might help you with it.

**Update:**
Ah, it's in debug, as in debug mode, not DEBUG target, is it ?!... 
If you are trying to see the result in quick watch or immediate window - it's expected error. This doesn't mean that there is something wrong with the code, just that debugger doesn't like lambda expressions.

Comment: DK, Thanks, but this not helped me. I bad read\write on English. on this I can not understand the meaning of the discussion. And your example not helped.

Comment: @simply denis, the example is just to verify that your OrderBy() syntax is ok. The next question is what DaveShaw is asking: what is the parameter in your OrderBy and if compiler can tell the type of a.id?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot inspect Lambda expressions at runtime. They need to be compiled, even changing a method containing a lambda (not just the lambda itself) at runtime requires recompilation.